# why non rooted android does not support sdcard formatted with ext4?

Tags: ext4

Prone to data loss, fat32 or exFat are the only options right?
I just lost many files on a sdcard.
Formatted on linux desktop, to ext4, android will not reconize the sdcard, despite it could.

my question is: why this non-sense?

lollipop here :(

is our only option for quality, to root the smartphone?

Comment: Root alone won't help you most likely, pure AOSP code does not allow external storage to be anything except FAT. Your assumption here that ext4 is superior to FAT file systems because they are "prone to data loss" is just plain wrong. FAT filesystems have been around for 30 years and are NOT prone to data loss at all. SD cards, particularly ones of lower quality, are quite susceptible to data loss or "wear errors" regardless of filesystem. You are chasing the wrong problem.

Comment: @acejavelin could you actually explain why it is not superior? have you ever read about the journaling feature of Ext4? if FAT were at least equivalent, the very android internal filesystem would not be an Ext filesystem... it would just be FAT. Long time in informatics doesnt mean quality, actually it means it is just very well known and spread. My sdcard was not expensive, but it lasted for several years w/o a single problem. Now I just reformated it to exFat and it is working well, but the question is: for how long?If it was ext4, I could rest tranquil, now I have to make backups to be sure

Answer (score 0):

yes , not make any sense , the better I could get until now is mount ext4 , with adb root

[Mounting a ext4 formatted sdcard on Android Marshmallow](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176203/mounting-a-ext4-formatted-sdcard-on-android-marshmallow)

more info here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204616/119381